# Tableview header cell expand with same cardView in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have attached the image click the card view expands the same card inside the table cell dynamically its passible to achieve this?

[image: Click the image url]

I have searched a lot but not working

Hear my code added header cell with CardView 
added arrow button to click the button expand the cell 
its able expand but not in parent card it was showing diff card

I have adde my source code

```
 var hiddenSections = Set<Int>()
       let tableViewData = [
           ["1","2","3","4","5"],
           ["1","2","3","4","5"],
           ["1","2","3","4","5"],
       ]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

     let CustomeHeaderNib = UINib(nibName: "CustomSectionHeader", bundle: Bundle.main)
            historyTableView.register(CustomeHeaderNib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "customSectionHeader")
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.tableViewData.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.hiddenSections.contains(section) {
        return 0
    }
    return self.tableViewData[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->    UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableViewData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]        
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return view.frame.width/4
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
let header = self.historyTableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "customSectionHeader") as! CustomSectionHeader
        header.setupCornerRadious()
        let sectionButton = header.expandBtn
        sectionButton?.setTitle(String(section),
                               for: .normal)
        sectionButton?.tag = section
        sectionButton?.addTarget(self,action: #selector(self.hideSection(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return header
    }
     @objc
private func hideSection(sender: UIButton) {
    let section = sender.tag

    func indexPathsForSection() -> [IndexPath] {
        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

        for row in 0..<self.tableViewData[section].count {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row,
                                        section: section))
        }

        return indexPaths
    }

    if self.hiddenSections.contains(section) {
        self.hiddenSections.remove(section)
        self.historyTableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsForSection(),
                                  with: .fade)
    } else {
        self.hiddenSections.insert(section)
        self.historyTableView.deleteRows(at: indexPathsForSection(),
                                  with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution? I am looking for same can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

With out sections also you can achieve this. To do this,

1.Return cell height as section height. If user clicks on the cell then return total content height to the particular cell.

2.You need to take an array, if user selects cell, add indexPath number in to array. If selects already expand cell remove it from array. In height for row at index check indexPath is in array or not.

This is one of the way. With sections also you can do that.

Comment: How to do that can you please share if you have any samples?

Comment: I already did this. I am unable to share that code. But I will send you sample code. Give me some time I will send it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//MARK:- UITableView Related Methods
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrDict.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    //        var cel = tblExpandedTest.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("expCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CDTableViewCell

    var cel : CaseHearingTabTVC! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "caseHearingTabCell") as! CaseHearingTabTVC

    if(cel == nil)
    {
        cel = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("caseHearingTabCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CaseHearingTabTVC;
    }

    //cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    cel.delegate = self


    if indexPath != selctedIndexPath{
        cel.subview_desc.isHidden = true
        cel.subview_remarks.isHidden = true
        cel.lblHearingTime.isHidden = true
    }
    else {
        cel.subview_desc.isHidden = false
        cel.subview_remarks.isHidden = false
        cel.lblHearingTime.isHidden = false
    }
    return cel

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectIndex = true;

    if(selectedInd == indexPath.row) {
        selectedInd = -1
    }
    else{
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! CaseHearingTabTVC
        cellUpdatedHeight = Float(currentCell.lblHearingTime.frame.origin.y + currentCell.lblHearingTime.frame.size.height) + 2;

        selectedInd = -1
        tblCaseHearing.reloadData()
        selectedInd = indexPath.row
    }

    let previousPth = selctedIndexPath

    if indexPath == selctedIndexPath{
        selctedIndexPath = nil
    }else{
        selctedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    var indexPaths : Array<IndexPath> = []
    if let previous = previousPth{
        indexPaths = [previous]
    }
    if let current = selctedIndexPath{
        indexPaths = [current]
    }
    if indexPaths.count>0{
        tblCaseHearing.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) {

    (cell as! CaseHearingTabTVC).watchFrameChanges()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) {

    (cell as! CaseHearingTabTVC).ignoreFrameChanges()
}

func tableView(_ TableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    if indexPath == selctedIndexPath{
        return CGFloat(cellUpdatedHeight)

    }else{
        return CaseHearingTabTVC.defaultHeight
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Best approach is to create two different cells for normal card and expanded card. 

fileprivate var selectedIndex: Int?

func registerTableViewCells() {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:Nib.CardCell , bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CardCell")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName:Nib.ExpandedCardCell , bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ExpandedCardCell")

    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.registerTableViewCells()
 }
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

```
    guard let index = selectedIndex else {
            return 115
        }
        if index == indexPath.row{
            return 200
        }
        return 115
    }
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    if let selected = selectedIndex, selected == indexPath.row{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExpandedCardCell", for: indexPath) as! ExpandedCardCell
        return cell
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCell

    return cell

}
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row{
            selectedIndex = nil
        }
        else{
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }


}
```